# Video not playing when called by http request

Tags: javascript, html, express

i created a javascprit file to listen to http port 3000 and send a html file which plays a video file

```js
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require('path')

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/vid_1.html")
}
)

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
    console.log(__dirname)
})
```

the hmtl file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <video controls>
            <source src="vid_1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <p>
              Your browser doesn't support HTML video. Here is a
              <a href="vid_1.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.
            </p>
          </video>
    </body>
 </html>
```

when i call the http://localhost:3000 the video player starts but no video is played but when i directly run my index.html the video plays can someone please help me

i tried sending the video file directly as a response without the html file which worked but i need to use a html file for the project i am bulding

Comment: Well, what happens when you go to http://localhost:3000/vid_1.mp4? Does it serve your video file there? No. Because your server is only set up to serve one HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can only send one file with res.sendFile(). You should serve the vid_1.mp4 route similar to the html page like this:

```
app.get("/vid_1.mp4", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/vid_1.mp4")
})
```

You could also have a public folder to serve many more files like this. You can find more about this here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: actually i tried this but i want to make it so that the user gets a webpage with a video playing while they can interact with other elements but when i use
```
app.get("/vid.mp4", (req,res) +> {
                  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/vid_1.mp4")
})
```
only the video is played with the controls like in netflix while what is want is something like youtube

Comment: You should just be able to add the `autoplay="autoplay"` attribute on your video tag  if that is what you want.